# What is this stack-checking PPC assembly doing?

Tags: assembly, stack, powerpc

I have the following self-contained function (i.e. it is branched to using `bl CheckStackFunc`) and I am mystified as to its purpose. Could someone familiar with PowerPC assembly lend a hand?

```
_CheckStackFunc:
    neg     %r11, %r12
    addi    %r0, %r11, 0xFFF
    srawi.  %r0, %r0, 0xC
    blelr
    mr      %r11, %sp
    mtctr   %r0
loc_10176B0C:                           
    lwzu    %r0, -0x1000(%r11)
    bdnz    loc_10176B0C
    blr
```

That having been said, I am using [this](http://www.ibm.com/chips/techlib/techlib.nsf/techdocs/852569B20050FF778525699600719DF2) document by IBM for my PPC assembly reference. Is this considered the definitive source or are there others I should be aware of?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not familiar at all with PPC, but here is my guess:

It looks like `alloca_probe()` to me. The code that *touches* the stack with steps of a page so that it would trigger the `PAGE_GUARD` exceptions. (please excuse my x86 language :) )

It is used after a large stack allocation (that can also be done by `alloca`). The stack usually don't have all the memory reserved for stack allocated, the last actually loaded page have a special flag, `PAGE_GUARD`, that triggers a hardware exception that is caught by OS, so that it could commit more pages to the stack. When the stack is used normally (with push/pop), then this page cannot be bypassed. However, for larger allocs, a call to `alloca_probe()` is required before memory can be safely used.

Comment: Brilliant, that looks like it's precisly what it is. Thank you for such a prompt response -- and elaborating on it. Very much appreciated.

Comment: You're welcome. I've spent some time with `alloca_probe` too once :)